# "Unprocessable entity" when trying to change the fulfilment status of an order IN SHOPIFY

Tags: shopify

I m trying to change the fulfilment status of an order , this is the json
data sent :

{"fulfillment":{"tracking_number":null,"line_items":[{"id":"XXXXXXX"}]}} and this is the url "/admin/orders/XXXXXXXXX/fulfillments.json"
but i get this error "Unprocessable entity" .

looking for your help .

thanks
Alaeddine

Comment: What HTTP method are you using on your request? Also, try removing the quotes around the line item id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was the body of the response?

"Unprocessable entity" is a 422 HTTP response, which is generally used for validation errors.  Validation errors will generally have a description of the error in the body of the response which might help debug the problem.

Edit: As David Underwood mentioned:

> The ID you need to provide is for the line item, not the variant. When you fetch the order you'll see the ids of the line items in the response. Those are the ones you need when creating the fulfillment.

Comment: here's the reponse :  "Can not fulfill line items from another order", but i m sure the variant Id blongs to that order , i verified it agan and again .

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if the order and/or line item has already been fulfilled. Another common issue is not setting the accept and content type headers for your request.

If that isn't the case and the other suggestions done help could you post the order I'd so we can look into what is happening in your specific case?

Comment: here's the error : "Can not fulfill line items from another order", i checked it and i found that the variant ID belongs to that order .

Comment: The ID you need to provide is for the line item, not the variant. When you fetch the order you'll see the ids of the line items in the response. Those are the ones you need when creating the fulfillment.